# Using uint32_t* to change value of uint8_t array

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Consider I have 2 unsigned numbers, of 32 bits each, saved in a single array. The first number is contained in positions [0; 3] and the second in positions [4; 8]. I now which to change the value of one of the numbers, is the following code allowed/problematic?

```
uint8_t array[8];
//...Fill it up...

uint32_t *ptr = NULL;
ptr = (uint32_t*)&array[0];
*ptr = 12345;

ptr = (uint32_t*)&array[4];
*ptr = 54321;
```

Comment: yes, it is problematic, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Comment: You violate effective type (aka strict aliasing) rule. This is a clear **don't**! Use marshalling with bitshifts/masking.

Comment: you can do it the other way around though : have an array of  `uint32_t`, which you fill up with the `uint32_t` values. You can then "read" that array with a `uint8_t*` (as long as you're not bothered by the data representation).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: That is also a bad idea, as it does not account for implementation-specifics. What problem do people have with shifting??

Comment: @Olaf : I don't have a problem with bit shifting (and would prefer it personally - although I'd use functions like `htonl` rather than doing so manually), but given the caveat I added about the value representation (which are the implementation specifics you're referring to) there's no problem with the approach I mentioned either.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Such code is almost always used for mashalling. A well defined data representation is important for this, so of course the data-representation **does** matter. Re 'htonl` etc.: They are not available on most targets C is used for. They are not even part of the C standard.

Comment: @Olaf : I don't know what the OP wants to use this for - for all I know, he just wants to do a hex dump. Or maybe the data representation is always the same in the scenario's where the code will be used. All this to say that there are valid uses for both the approach you mentioned, and the approach I mentioned. There's no reason to disparage either of them.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: As I wrote: marshalling (you might want to read about it!). As your approach has portability issues and relies on UB for one direction, it very well should not be used. Implemented with a common pattern the shift-variant has good chances the compiler optimizes the code well. It has no drawback like yours. Another point is that typical I/O functions take a `uint8_t *`, not an `uint32_t *` etc. So using the correct buffer type helps, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122908/discussion-between-sander-de-dycker-and-olaf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not access an `uint8_t` array with a pointer to `uint32_t`. That's a violation of [the strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/1116364) (the other way around would be ok - if `uint8_t` is a character type).

Instead, you might want to use "[type punning"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) to circumvent the C (C99 and above) type system. For that, you use a `union` with members of the respective types:

```
union TypePunning {
  uint32_t the_ints[2];
  uint8_t the_bytes[2 * sizeof(uint32_t)];
}
// now e.g. write to the_bytes[1] and see the effect in the_ints[0].
// Beware of system endianness, though!
```

Comment: `uint8_t` is never a character type! It always is an unsigned integer type. And the other way in not ok. See 6.5p6, 1st sentence! And while not invoking UB, the union-approach has also its issues.

Comment: @Olaf, better to say that `uint8_t` is an integer type and `char` is not.  The standard has no broader category of "character types".  In particular, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are not grouped with `char` to form such a category; the signed / unsigned types are grouped among the integer types.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: 6.2.5p6, last sentence: "... The standard and extended unsigned integer types are collectively called _unsigned integer types_". `uint8_t` cannot be anything else than `unsigned char` which is a _standard unsigned integer type_.

Comment: @Olaf, yes, but the standard has no collective term "character types".  That's all I'm saying.  It's nitpicky.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Oh, you were extending on my comment. Sorry, I didn't get that. But you are wrong - when it comes to nitpicking;-). See 6.2.5p15: "The three types char, signed char, and unsigned char are collectively called the **character types**." But it has no distince character type like Pascal/Modula/etc. which cannot be used as integer without explicit conversion, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @Olaf, well, darn.  I *looked* for that, and somehow overlooked it.

Comment: "You may not access an uint8_t array with a pointer to uint32_t." Is this true even though the information contained in the array is actually a 32bit number split into 4 pieces? Is this a compiler limitation? Because in terms of memory arrangement, since all the bytes of the array are contiguous, it seems to be a valid operation.